# Issue with Glassfish 5 / Unable to modify SSL settings

Tags: ssl, glassfish

I'm trying to modify SSL settings for one of the http-listeners through the web console but I keep getting this error message

> Could not apply changes: No configuration found for
>   configs.config.default-config.network-config.protocols.protocol.http-listener-1.ssl

Basically I have a REST (jax-rs) application deployed on this server and I want to enable https.Once I log into the web console , I go into  Configurations/server-config/HTTP-Service/Http Listeners/http-listerner 1 , then I go into the SSL tab , there I try to modiify the settings(add Key Store , certificate name etc...) but I get the same error with whatever option I chose. I've tried to create another listener , same thing.I checked the domain.xml file but not quite sure what to look for.Need help !!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

GlassFish, by default, has two configs which are effectively the same: `default-config` and `server-config`. The key difference is that the `default-config` is not actually used; it's provided as a template so you can create new server instances based on the same standard settings.

The one you want is `server-config`. The error message you pasted names the `default-config`, so it seems that you were trying to make the change in the wrong place.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I actually get the same error in server-config !

Comment: Could you add some more detail in the question as to what steps you take to get that error? What your expectations were and how you tried to complete the task?